# Final variable with static access modifier

Tags: java

I am a beginner at Java. I am learning final variables, and tried this code.

```
package taopablot;


    class Person
    {
    String name;
    public void myPerson(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println(this.name);
    }
    }

    public class Final {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    static final String name = "Pablo";
    Person person = new Person();
    Person person2 = new Person();
    Person person3 = new Person();
    person.myPerson(name);
    person2.myPerson(name);
    person3.myPerson(name);


    }   
}
```

However, Eclipse gives me an error.

```
Illegal modifier for parameter name; only final is permitted.
```

What am I doing wrong? And how do I set a final variable to be static for all objects?

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is local to a method is not possible to assign any access modifier.

The variable must be in the body of the class.

```
public class Final {
    // Moved out of main body in the Final body
    static final String name = "Pablo";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Removed from here
        // static final String name = "Pablo";

        Person person = new Person();
        Person person2 = new Person();
        Person person3 = new Person();
        person.myPerson(name);
        person2.myPerson(name);
        person3.myPerson(name);
     }   
}
```

A local variable (local to method, or a block) is visible only in the method (or block) where it is defined. It is not possible to add any modifier to that variable.

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html):

> There is **no special keyword designating a variable as local**; that determination comes entirely from the location in which the variable is declared — which is between the opening and closing braces of a method. As such, local variables are only visible to the methods in which they are declared; they are not accessible from the rest of the class.

Comment: So the variable name is local to the main method?

Comment: If a variable is local to the main method (like person, person2, person3) you can't add modifiers to this variable.

Comment: What about variables local to other methods, other than the main method, can I add modifiers to those?

Comment: It is exactly the same. If a variable is defined inside the body of a method is visible only to that method. I added the relative part of oracle documentation in the answer

Comment: Okay, so you can't add any access modifiers within methods. They must be an instance variable?

Comment: Instance variable or class variable (if you add the static keyword). Basically any variable defined in the body of the class and out of the body of any method